# Eclipse RCP custom launch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm totally new to eclipse. I started developing an Eclipse product to realize a custom IDE.
I would like to know if i could create a custom "Run" and "Debug" action to launch an application. I would like not to add the default menus and toolbar entries for these actions.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in your menu and tool bar is created by your RCP's ActionBarAdvisor. You can choose not to add the Run & Debug items.

Programmatically you can create/edit/find a launch configuration and launch it. See

http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html
http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html

for more details

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

if you want to have different settings for run than for debug, you need two launch configs. if you want to start your rcp application without all the eclipse/target platform plugins than you have to change the lauch configs.

Click on "Debug Configurations ..." or "Run Configurations ..." using the small triangle right to the buttons. select the launch config and then the "plug-ins tab". change "Launch with:" to "plug-ins selected below only" and press the "Add Required Plug-ins" Button. Now your Application should start without the IDE Plugins.